# Ways to call a pdf inside a frame

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

One way by which we can call a pdf inside a frame is by directly seeting the src property..

```
<frame src="xyz.pdf" .../>
```

Is there any other way (apart from frame/object/embed) to call the pdf within the frame...something like the frame actually has some html code and within that pdf is called...

I know sounds a bit funny, but is there any way...I need this as I am trying to fix a scrolling issue for pdf within a frame for iPad?

Thank you.

Comment: For reference, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/best-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html

Comment: have you tried an iframe or an object tag?

Comment: yes, but with an object, I can only scroll if I  give fixed height...But my pdf no of pgs vary..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, avoid frames when you can. It's **always** bad practice.

Here is the source for a very simple HTML page that would redirect to the PDF after one second:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=xyz.pdf">
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

I don't understand how this would solve your scrolling issue, but it will definitely do what you ask for in your question.

Comment: You code will a) not work in my firefox, b) break the back button - when it comes to PDF, (i)frames are VERY MUCH better than anything else.

Comment: @mplungjan Are you serious? In what way are frames better than ANYTHING?

Comment: In the case of embedding pdfs. iframes and frames reacts much more controlled and reliant than other ways of showing pdf. meta refresh is so 1994 and currently does not work at all in any firefox I have had since version 3,x